# Unity2D - Stop movement direction once user input returns to zero but keep same direction facing

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have come to the end of my patience, I am learning and trying to create a simple character controller. My animation is all set correctly but my script seems to keep my player moving in the last known input direction.

Where I want my player to stop moving all together once user input has returned to 0 but keep facing the last known direction i.e up, down, right or left. simply just freeze that animation frame on last directional input.

But he just keeps walking. can someone help me please?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
public float moveSpeed = 5.0f;
private Vector2 moveDirection;
private Vector2 lastMoveDirection;
private bool playerMoving;
private Rigidbody2D rb;
private Animator anim;
private static bool playerExists;

void Start()
{
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    anim = GetComponent<Animator>();

    if (!playerExists)
    {
        playerExists = true;
        DontDestroyOnLoad(transform.gameObject);
    }
    else
    {
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }

}

void Update()
{
    moveDirection = new Vector2(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal"), Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical"));
    // Mobile controls
    if (Input.touchCount > 0)
    {
        Touch touch = Input.GetTouch(0);
        if (touch.position.x < Screen.width / 2)
            moveDirection.x = -1;
        else
            moveDirection.x = 1;

        if (touch.position.y < Screen.height / 2)
            moveDirection.y = -1;
        else
            moveDirection.y = 1;
    }
    // Limit the movement to only horizontal or vertical


    if (Mathf.Abs(moveDirection.x) > Mathf.Abs(moveDirection.y))
        moveDirection.y = 0;
    else
        moveDirection.x = 0;

    // replace moveDirection with lastMoveDirection when input is zero
    if (moveDirection == Vector2.zero) {
        moveDirection = lastMoveDirection;
    } else {
        lastMoveDirection = moveDirection;
    }

    anim.SetFloat("MoveX", moveDirection.x);
    anim.SetFloat("MoveY", moveDirection.y);
    anim.SetBool("PlayerMoving", moveDirection != Vector2.zero);

}

void FixedUpdate()
{
    rb.MovePosition(rb.position + moveDirection * moveSpeed * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Opps worked it out.. Thanks to those who looked though.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float moveSpeed = 5.0f;
    private Vector2 moveDirection;
    private Vector2 lastMoveDirection;
    private bool playerMoving;
    private Rigidbody2D rb;
    private Animator anim;
    private static bool playerExists;

    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        anim = GetComponent<Animator>();

        if (!playerExists)
        {
            playerExists = true;
            DontDestroyOnLoad(transform.gameObject);
        }
        else
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }

    }

    void Update()
    {
        moveDirection = new Vector2(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal"), Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical"));
        // Mobile controls
        if (Input.touchCount > 0)
        {
            Touch touch = Input.GetTouch(0);
            if (touch.position.x < Screen.width / 2)
                moveDirection.x = -1;
            else
                moveDirection.x = 1;

            if (touch.position.y < Screen.height / 2)
                moveDirection.y = -1;
            else
                moveDirection.y = 1;
        }
        // Limit the movement to only horizontal or vertical


        if (Mathf.Abs(moveDirection.x) > Mathf.Abs(moveDirection.y))
            moveDirection.y = 0;
        else
            moveDirection.x = 0;
        
        if (moveDirection == Vector2.zero) {
            moveDirection = lastMoveDirection;
            moveDirection = Vector2.zero;
        } else {
            lastMoveDirection = moveDirection;
        }

        anim.SetFloat("MoveX", lastMoveDirection.x);
        anim.SetFloat("MoveY", lastMoveDirection.y);
        anim.SetBool("PlayerMoving", moveDirection != Vector2.zero);

    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        rb.MovePosition(rb.position + moveDirection * moveSpeed * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
    }

}
```